# XPages - Bootstrap Customization Affects valuePicker Behaviour

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Without Customization - valuePicker works fine
https://serveragi12.agi-imc.de/BootstrapTest.nsf

With Customization (modified bootstrap.min.css as resource in Theme) - valuePicker not working
https://serveragi12.agi-imc.de/BootstrapTestCustomized.nsf

Compare the button appearance for the two cases, background-color for btn-warning modified and taking effect.

MORE INFO:
The only difference is that in the customized case the backround-color of a button was modified in the bootstrap.min.css, and that bootstrap.min.css was then referenced as a resource in the theme.

It is strange that changing of a background-color can affect the functioning of a valuePicker.

THEME CODE (for BootstrapTestCustomized):

```
<theme extends="Bootstrap3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd">

<resource>
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>/css/bootstrap.min.css</href>
    <media>screen</media>
</resource>

</theme>
```

Comment: The difference in button style occurs because BootstrapTestCustomized explicitely links ".../css/bootstrap.min.css" in the head and the contained styles for `btn-warning` etc. overwrite the defaults from "/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/css-1.9.7/@B3r&@B3o&@B3m&@B3p&@B3s.css"

Comment: When opening the valuePicker in BootstrapTestCustomized the response from the server is empty, indicating that the problem might occur due to different underlying data rather than a display issue.

Comment: The underlying values are the same - in both cases the valuePicker has a hardcoded valueList (A, B, C, ...).

Comment: I assume you verified that `BootstrapTestCustomized` behaves exactly like `BootstrapTest` if you remove the reference to `bootstrap.min.css` from the theme...

Comment: Yes, removing the reference to bootstrap.min.css from the theme for BootstrapTestCustomized results in the same, and OK, behaviour for the valuePicker. The problem was observed in a larger project, and to understand the behaviour, the two test databases with only relevant code were prepared.

Comment: Could you add the theme code to your question?